# Rescue SubclassNotFound error in STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance, rescue

Is there a best-practices or idiomatic way to rescue an `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound` error inside the model for the base class (Rails 2.3.8)? I'd really like to be able to do something like call `BaseClass.all` when there are known broken types in the database and be able to rescue always, without having to write a `begin...rescue...end` each individual time this find is done.

Comment: We're actually attempting to leverage STI to dynamically create the sub-classes, and we want to trigger a dynamic class creation when a class is not found. It looks like we're probably going to use Rails initializers to monkeypatch find_sti_class. However, other ideas would be very appreciated still.